# How can I optimize the process of creating a multi-level graph selection (VUE3 °

Tags: graph, vuejs3

I'm working on a web application using .NET and Vue3, and I need to optimize the process of creating a graph with multiple levels of components selection. Currently, the left-hand side of the screen displays a list of components, with the first list showing only the "Parent" components. Subsequent lists only appear when the user clicks on the desired element to reveal the next level of components. To create the graph, the user must select the "Server" parent element and fill out the required information in a pop-up window that automatically closes when complete. The user can then select a child element from the list that appears and repeat this process until the "Child-4" level is reached. Once complete, the graph can be viewed on the right-hand side of the screen and executed by clicking the "Confirm" button.

What tools or techniques can I use to optimize this process and make it more user-friendly? Any suggestions for the best way to design the graph in this scenario?